# How to use neo4j rest api to post multiple nodes and their relationships through a single request?

Tags: neo4j, jersey, neo4jrestclient

I'm new to neo4j. I want to use the neo4j rest api to post a stream of edges of a graph (more than million nodes and their relationships) to neo4j.

I'm reading the edges from a dataset and using a jersey client to post the edges to neo4j. What i understood from the REST api documentation is that to create an edge, i have to create two nodes by sending a post request to the /node uri and then obtain the id of the created node from the response and send the relationship (edge) to the node/id/relationships uri after that. Is that the correct way to do that? How do i post multiple nodes and their relationships through a single request?

Comment: currently i'm reading a single edge from the graph dataset and obtaining the two nodes comprised in that edge and then sending 2 post requests to /node uri and another post request to node/id/relationship uri to create the edge in neo4j. Can you please explain how to do this using cypher to send multiple nodes and their relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cypher you would do something like this:

```
MATCH (n:NodeType {some:'condition'})
MATCH (o:OtherNodeType {another:'condition'})
CREATE (n) - [:EdgeType] -> (o)
```

This finds two nodes n and o and then creates a relationship (edge) between.

I havent personally used the rest client direcly but there will be a call to pass a cypher query.

Comment: Thank you very much. i used the following cypher query format to create multiple nodes and the corresponding edges from a single request. But this creates duplicate nodes.                                                                                                           CREATE (a:Node { name : 1})-[:CONNECTED]->(b:Node { name : 2}),
                (c:Node { name : 3})-[:CONNECTED]->(d:Node { name : 4}),
                (e:Node { name : 3})-[:CONNECTED]->(f:Node { name : 4})

Comment: You have told it to create both the nodes and the relationships as you havent used a match first. You can use merge to do an upsert instead